# Bash programming : How to run a program in a different "shell", similar to the CLI commands more|less etc

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My goal is to run a program from my main shell, then clear the screen, display all the output in this newly cleared shell until my program exits. at that time, I do not want to see in my screen history all the outputs from this program. But I do not want to lose previous history.

clear, reset, clear && printf '\e[3J' does not work. Subshell keeps the history and is not working either.

Thanks

Comment: By "history", do you mean saved lines of text in your terminal emulator (e.g., xterm, mate-terminal)?  By "shell" do you mean the commandline interpreter (e.g., bash, csh)?  Does your program clear the screen or do you want to do that manually?

Comment: Have you considered using [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html)?

Comment: You are referring to the "alternate screen" provided by many terminal types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
tput smcup    # Save the display
...
echo 'Your program stuff...'
...
tput rmcup    # restore the display
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just about displaying your script's output, you can simply pipe that into `less`.

Comment: It's a live program output. See Eric's answer above, this fit my needs. Tx